# do not have mouse tracking support in nw.js

Tags: node-webkit

I want to listen to mouseleave when mouse leave window and listen to mouseenter when mouse enter window。

```
$('.report').on('mouseenter', function(){
   $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
   $(this).css('border', '0');
});
```

but when i move my mouse fast, events will be triggerd, but when i move slowly, nothing happend. (I tested it on windows 7)

In many apps, we have to know whether mouse is outside or inside the window. Like some notification window, when mouse leaves, the window will be closed. But this feature cannot be achieved at this moment

what should i do?